# Is it possible to include multiple modules in a single "include" statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module

Is there a shorter way to do the following?

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule1
  include MyModule2
  include MyModule3
end
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try following

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule3, MyModule2, MyModule1
end
```

Edit: reversed the sequence

Comment: It *looks* like that's the same, but you've actually reversed the ancestry here. If all three defined the same method he'd get the Module3 version whereas your one line version would yield the Module1.

Comment: Surely then the answer below should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 30):

to get the same ancestry order you need to reverse the order in the one line version

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule3, MyModule2, MyModule1
end
```